# How to bind html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have scope variable.like

```
$scope.demo='<h1>This is test</h1>';
```

I can bind html using `ng-bind-html` like

```
<p ng-bind-html="demo"></p>
```

Its working fine but how can bind html inside  `{{  .. }}`

Comment: It will be better to use templates instead of doing so.

Comment: what this mean `Its working fine but how can bind html inside  {{  .. }}` ?

Comment: is html binding to view working fine for you ?? If yes then whats the problem  ?

Comment: i dont need to bind inside any html tag like p,span etc

Comment: Okay . I think replacing the content of element tag will work for you.! Right ?     You can use directive to do that

Comment: @KishorP - Check jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mLgnm2ae/ for directive code to replace the content . Apply it on the element <p> in above example .Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to sanitize the html using [**`$sce`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service, which needs `ngSanitize` module injected in your app.

Basically you need to allow html as `trustAsHtml` mehthod of `$sce` service.

**Code**

```
$scope.demo = $sce.trustAsHtml('<h1>This is test</h1>');
```

**Better way**

For making it more better you could create an custom filter and reuse that code

```
app.filter('trsustedhtml', function($sce) { 
    return $sce.trustAsHtml; 
});
```

**Markup**

```
<p ng-bind-html="demo| trsustedhtml"></p>
```

Comment: I want use like {{ demo  }}

Comment: we are uses {{ //scope variable }} to view on html side.also we can use angular directive like {{ demo | diretive.. }} then how can use ng-bind-html on it

Comment: i dont need to bind inside any html tag like p,span etc

Comment: @KishorP oh then you need to compile that html..because `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile the html..

Answer (score -4):

ng-bind html only take the text, you have to remove the safe control

```
<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="demo"></p>
```

Comment: i don't need to use any tag

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated since 1.2 +

Comment: @pankaj i have an application that use it and it works:)