# AngularJS converting a link into a link tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a quick question regarding AngularJS and the only way to explain my question is by the following example:

I have a controller and inside the controller I have a list of objects. Each object has a property that is actualy link to another page. However, when using ng-repeat is it possible to use the following structure so the link can be converted to a  tag?

```
<a href="{{object.linkProperty}}"> {{object.name}} <</a>
```

Another question with the same meaning is the following:
If for example the object containes a property which I would like to represent as a table how can I do this? In other words:

```
listOfObjects = [
    { name: "bla"
      info: "<table> some data </table>"
    }
    { name: "blaTwo"
      info: "<table> some data </table>"
    }
]
```

I know that if I use ng-repeat abd {{object.info}} it woud give me the string and it would not convert it to an hmtl tag. However, I would like to convert it to an HTML tag. I know that templates are used for this, but I am not sure how to use a template in the object.

Thank you very much for any help in advance! = )

Comment: `ng-bind-html` with `$sce.trustedAsHtml` will do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/32269118/2435473

Comment: @Polly You could also use your html as the template to a directive. That is using the `$compile` service to dynamically compile the html. But depending on your use case as `Pankaj Parkar` says `ng-bind-html` may be better. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, yes but you should use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

```
<a ng-href="{{object.linkProperty}}"> {{object.name}} </a>
```

ngHref will wait until it has all the data before adding the final href to the tag, preventing strange edge-cases where people click the link before it is ready. This is usually not a problem on hrefs (but still best practise) but the similar [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) for images is very usefull for stopping a broken image to flash before angular inserts the correct src.

For the sectond question you can either use ng-bind-html with $sce.trustedAsHtml as the comments have mentioned, or you could just template inside the repeat.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="object in listOfObjects">
        <td>{{object.name}}</td>
        <td>{{object.moreProperties}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would say this is the much better way most of the time. It's easier and much more readable, when using ng-bind-html you can't just read your template and see what the result will be, so only use that solution when the content is truly unknown (such as sent from the backend). If you know the structure it should have, write it in the template.